# Condition to get the NULL values and Blank values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help in creating the condition in `stored procedure`.

I have a two columns in my `sp` named `col1,col2` and actually i have a data in my view named`[SampleData]` and in this view i have one `column [col_new]` which has both `NULL values` and `Blank Values`.

**The Condition is:**

If the `[col_new]` has an `NULL`, then display the `[col_new] NULL` in the `col1 field`.

If the `[col_new]` has a Blank, then display the `[col_new] Blank` in the `col2 field`.

So how can i add the `condition` here using if and `else in CASE Condition`?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want `case` expressions?

```
select (case when col_new is null then '[col_new] is null' end) as col1,
       (case when col_new = '' then '[col_new] is blank' end) as col2
from SampleData;
```

Comment: Hi if a get the null value then i need to map the value with col1 and if blank then col2. So how to do that one? Can we use if else statement?

Comment: `IF...ELSE` is a logical flow process, @Vinayakss, it's not an expression you can use within a statement (like `SELECT`)

Comment: As i said i have NULL values and Blank values in single column i,e [col_new].

And in my sp i need to populate these values that means if i have NULL value then i need to display in col1 which is create in sp and if i have blank value then i need to display it in col2.

i need to get these two (NULL and Blank)values from single column and display them in two different columns(col1,col2) in sp.

Is that possible with help of CASE statement?

Comment: @Vinayakss The above answer should work for you. If you need anything more, could you clarify with some more details?

Comment: @Vinayakss Did you state it backwards perhaps?  `case when col_new is null then col1 else case when col_new = '' then col2 end end as col_new`